# Entity Framework 5 upgrade from 4

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I'm having an issue with the Where clause in a search, in my original version EF4 I could add a Where clause with  2 parameters, the where clause (string predicate) and a ObjectParameter list such as

```
var query = context.entities.Where(WhereClause.ToString(), Params.ToArray());
```

since my upgrade to EF5 I don't seem to have that option am I missing something?

This was originally used to build dynamic where clause such as "it.entity_id = @entity_id" then holding the variable value in the ObjectParameter.

I'm hoping I don't have to rewrite all the searches that have been built out this way, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use ESQL with DbContext, you will have to "drop down" to ObjectContext.

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
var query = objectContext.CreateQuery<MyEntity>(
    WhereClause.ToString(),
    Params.ToArray());
```